# CakePHP Translate behavior and $this->paginate['fields']

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, pagination

I have attached the translate behavior at a model and inside the controller in order to limit the fields queried I try to set the fields using:

```
$this->paginate['fields'] = 'Product.id, Product.category_id,...';
```

However, when trying to add a translatable field by adding it at

```
$this->paginate['fields'] = 'I18n__title.content, Product.id, Product.category_id,...';
```

I get

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'I18n__title.content' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
I should add the fields as an array instead of string

> It should work if you supply the fields as an array. String fields are not parsed, as SQL is complicated.

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/2348-translate-behavior-and-this-paginatefields#ticket-2348-3